# Why can we just change the wave number?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wave-equation

**Wave equation**: $u_{tt}=au_{xx}, a>0$

We are looking for solutions of the wave equation of the form of a wave function.

We suppose that $u(x,t)=A \cos(kx- \omega t)$ is a solution of $u_{tt}=au_{xx}, a>0$.

We have:

$$u_x(x,t)=-Ak \sin(kx- \omega t)\\u_{xx}(x,t)=-Ak^2 \cos(kx-\omega t)\\u_t(x,t)=-\omega A \sin(kx- \omega t)\\ u_{tt}(x,t)=-\omega^2 A \cos(kx-\omega t)$$

Thus, it has to hold that:

$$-A \omega^2 \cos(kx-\omega t)=-a A k^2 \cos(kx \omega t)$$

or equivalently

$$A(\omega^2-ak^2) \cos(kx-\omega t)=0 (\forall x,t \in \mathbb{R})$$

The above holds **if**  $\omega^2=ak^2$.

Thus $u(x,t)=Acos(k(x- \sqrt{a}t))$ is a solution of the wave equation of the form of a wave funcion, where $k>0$.

**Remark**:

At the above example we see that, if $k_1, k_2>0$ wave numbers with $k_1 \neq k_2$ then we have solutions of the form of a wavefunction

$$u_1(x,t)=A \cos(k_1(x- \sqrt{a}t))$$

$$u_2(x,t)=A \cos(k_2(x- \sqrt{a}t))$$

that "travel" with the same velocity $\sqrt{a}$.

Could you explain me why we can just change the wavenumber but let the circular frequency as it is?
I.e. why can we write the following?

$$u_1(x,t)=A \cos(k_1(x- \sqrt{a}t))$$

$$u_2(x,t)=A \cos(k_2(x- \sqrt{a}t))$$

Comment: Before your remark, you showed that you have solutions $A \cos(k(x-\sqrt{a}t))$ for any $k>0$. I don't see the problem.

Comment: I thought that we couldn't do this, since $\omega^2=ak^2$ and so $\omega$ depends on $k$. But we can do it since $A \cos{(k(x- \sqrt{a}t))}$ is a solution for any $k$, right? @Ian

Comment: In advance you have a two parameter family of solution candidates, depending on $\omega$ and $k$. You plug them in and you find the equation $\omega^2 = ak^2$ drops out. This makes one parameter dependent and leaves the other independent, which means you have a one parameter family of solutions. It is convenient to consider them explicitly depending on $k$ because this makes the resulting function depend only on $x-ct$ (where $c=\sqrt{a}$). This is not strictly necessary but makes for a nice presentation, and helps lead into the D'Alembert formula.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much!!! :-) @Ian

Comment: there is name for the constraint $\omega^2 = ak^2$ between the frequency $\omega$ and the wave number $k.$ it is called the dispersion relations. they tell you how the waves spread out as they evolve.